# SQL multiple SELECT too slow (7 min)

Tags: sql, select

This source is good but too slow.
Function:
Selecting all rows if SC and %%5 and 2013.07.11 < date < 2013.07.18
and
some older lines represent lines
Method:
Finding X count rows.
one by one to see whether there is consistency 28 days

```
select efi_name, efi_id, count(*) as dupes, id, mlap_date
from address m
where 
mlap_date > "2013.07.11"
and mlap_date < "2013.07.18"  
and mlap_type = "SC"
and calendar_id not like "%%5"

and  concat(efi_id,irsz,ucase(city), ucase(address)) in (
    select concat(k.efi_id,k.irsz,ucase(k.city), ucase(k.address)) as dupe
    from address k
    where k.mlap_date > adddate(m.`mlap_date`,-28)
    and k.mlap_date < m.mlap_date
    and k.mlap_type = "SC"
    and k.calendar_id not like "%%5"
    and k.status = 'Befejezett'
    group by concat(k.efi_id,k.irsz,ucase(k.city), ucase(k.address))
    having (count(*) > 1)
)
group by concat(efi_id,irsz,ucase(city), ucase(address))
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Replace CONCAT with matching one by one, otherwise it's comparing strings and too slow.

Comment: As davek said, I think changing the `WHERE IN` clause into a `INNER JOIN` one can solve the problem.

Comment: Why do you have a double `%` wildcard? Do you mean to use `__` instead?

Answer (score 1):

`NOT LIKE` plus wildcard-prefixed terms are index-usage killers.

You could also try replacing the `IN` + inline table with an `inner join`: does the optimizer run the `NOT LIKE` query twice (see your explain plan)?

It looks like you might be using MySql, in which case you could build a hash column based on

```
efi_id 
irsz
ucase(city)
ucase(address))
```

and compare that column directly. This is a way of implementing a hash join in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a subquery to do this.  You should be able to do it just with the outer `group by` and conditional aggregations.

```
select efi_name, efi_id,
       sum(case when mlap_date > "2013.07.11" and mlap_date < "2013.07.18" then 1 else 0 end) as dupes, 
       id, mlap_date
from address m
where mlap_type = 'SC' and calendar_id not like '%%5'
group by efi_id,irsz, ucase(city), ucase(address)
having sum(case when m.status = 'Befejezett' and
                     m.mlap_date <= '2013.07.11' and
                     k.mlap_date > adddate(date('2013.07.11'), -28)
                then 1
                else 0
           end) > 1
```

This produces a slightly different result from your query.  Instead of looking at the 28 days before each record, it looks at all records in the week period and then at the four weeks before that period.    Despite this subtle difference, it is still identifying dupes in the four-week period before the one-week period.